# Nightwatch.js 'Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server' for Firefox versions

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I've run into this enough and it's tricky enough to fix that it seemed worthwhile to add it here:

```
[My Test 0001] Test Suite
==================================

Running:  Load MY Auto Login page test

Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server
{ state: 'unhandled error',
  sessionId: null,
  hCode: 884712219,
  value: 
   { suppressed: [ [length]: 0 ],
     screen: null,
     cause: null,
     hCode: 1045402875,
     class: 'org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException',
     localizedMessage: 'Unable to connect to host localhost on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
```

Firefox (or Safari) opens up and then doesn't do anything or alternately crashes.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

HERE'S HOW I FIX IT:
Go to my nightwatch.json file and open it up.

Find

```
"selenium": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "./node_modules/[...]
```

Navigate to that path and figure out which version of the selenium-standalone-server jar you have.  (It's likely not the latest).

download the  newest selenium-standalone-server jar to that location by going here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and clicking on the link

Then update the path to have the new version number of the jar.